# Draw one by one image on screen from QList<QImage> in paintevent() method in Qt4.8

Tags: c++, shared-memory, qpainter, qimage, qt4.8

I am creating QImage reading from shared memory and adding to QList and in paintevent I want to draw all Images I have in QList but ending up with crash as shown in below code snippet.

I have created user defined paintImage() to read one by one from QList and QPainter and tried drawing although there is no crash but ending up with no images on screen.

```
    int fd = open("/run/user/1000/xpra.NanPLD.mmap", O_RDONLY);
    int filesize = 256*1024*1024;
    void* addr = mmap(NULL, filesize, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
    createImage(addr,width, height, offset, colorFormat);
    void Client::createImage(void* chunk,int width, int height, int offset, 
    QString colorFormat)
    {
            qDebug() << "offset Value " << offset;
            image = QImage(((const unsigned char*)chunk ) + offset, width, height, QImage::Format_RGB888);
            xpraImages.append(image);
    }

    void Client::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
    {
        qDebug() <<"Inside paint event" ;

        QPainter painter(this);
        static int counter = 0;
        qDebug() << "counter: " << counter; 
        qDebug() << "Image list length : " << xpraImages.count();       
        if(counter < xpraImages.count()){
            qDebug() << "counter " << counter;
            image = xpraImages.at(counter); // image is class member
            qWarning() << image.isNull() << image.width()<< image.height();
            if(!image.isNull()){
                qDebug() << "Inside paintvent after nullcheck";
                painter.drawImage(0,0,image); // here crashes
                            }
            counter++;
            QTimer::singleShot(50, this, SLOT(update()));

        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you show how `createImage` is called? Is `chunk` pointer still valid when `paintEvent` will be called? If not, you have undefined behaviour, because QImage doesn't copy chunk - it stores only pointer, no data is copied.

Comment: @rafix07, I have added createImage method in code section. Please have a look and do let me know what I am missing to lead to crash. thanks for your response and valuable time. much appreciated

Comment: You could try `xpraImages.append(image.copy());` - call `copy` to make deep copy instead of shallow copies of images. Are you calling `munmap` on `addr`?

Comment: @rafix07, no, I am not calling munmap yet.. sure, will try copying and keep u posted. thanks alot for ur time :-)

Comment: @rafix07, image.copy() leads to crash. I also tried making image as pointer and creating by means of new QImage(params) but still lead to crash.

Comment: @rafix07, this is the issue when image of different lengths streamed it ends up with crash. for your reference https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-14766?focusedCommentId=138908&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel

Comment: @moderator,, This problem is solved by having local image created on fly. than having image as a memeber of the class. please close this ticket .. Thank you, Rudresh